# How to get array of object's propety value in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can we return an array of object's property values?

```
[
    { id: 1, category: 'A'   },
    { id: 2, category: 'A'   },
    { id: 3, category: 'C'   },
    { id: 4, category: 'B'   },
    { id: 5, category: 'A'   },
]
```

I would like to get all the ids with category = 'A' `[1, 2, 5]` and using `.map()` include an undefined objects which i don't like and filter returns the entire object and not the id.

Using `.map()` output: `[1, 2, undefined, undefined, 5]`

using `.filter()` output:

```
[
    Object {
       category: 'A',
       id: 1
    },
    Object {
       category: 'A',
       id: 2
    },
    Object {
       category: 'A',
       id: 5,
    },
]
```

**[DEMO](https://codepen.io/badcoder28/pen/dRJGmG)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and then [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
var data = [{"id":1,"category":"A"},{"id":2,"category":"A"},{"id":3,"category":"C"},{"id":4,"category":"B"},{"id":5,"category":"A"}];

var result = data.filter(function(item) {
  return item.category === 'A';
}).map(function(item) {
  return item.id;
});

console.log(result);
```

Another option is to use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
var data = [{"id":1,"category":"A"},{"id":2,"category":"A"},{"id":3,"category":"C"},{"id":4,"category":"B"},{"id":5,"category":"A"}];

var result = data.reduce(function(items, item) {
  item.category === 'A' && items.push(item.id);
  
  return items;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: every time you use `reduce` this way, god kills a kitten

Comment: @georg - poor kittens & cruel god. I agree that it's not functional like mapping and then filtering. Any other cons?

Comment: is "not functional" not enough? reduce converts vectors to scalars. when you use it convert vectors to vectors, you're basically writing  a for loop with fancy syntax.

Comment: oh, and sorry about the kittens meme ;) didn't pay attention to your avatar. it wasn't intended...

Comment: @georg - great explanation of why not to use reduce in this way. And the poor kitten is probably dead anyway. We've lost him 9 years ago, but if not - shame on you!

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer then which means it is better to use filter().map() than reduce in this case?

Comment: The functional solution is filter and then map, which is more readable as well. Reduce is a bit better in terms of performance, since it doesn't create a temporary array, but as @georg pointed out, it's a fancy way of writing a for loop (which is more perfomant btw).

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with a single loop.

```js
var array = [{ id: 1, category: 'A'   }, { id: 2, category: 'A'   }, { id: 3, category: 'C'   }, { id: 4, category: 'B'   }, { id: 5, category: 'A'   }],
    category = 'A',
    result = array.reduce(function (r, o) {
        if (o.category === category) {
            r.push(o.id);
        }
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

you could combine both `filter()` and `map()`

```js
var data = [{ id: 1, category: 'A'   }, { id: 2, category: 'A'   }, { id: 3, category: 'C'   }, { id: 4, category: 'B'   }, { id: 5, category: 'A'   }]

var new_data_filter = data.filter(function(item) {
  if (item.category === 'A') {
      return item.id
  }
}).map(function(a){return a.id})
console.log(new_data_filter)
```

**For ES6**

```
var new_data_filter = data.filter(item => item.category === 'A').map(a => a.id)
```